# Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable in $[0,2]$.$f(0)=1,f(2)=3$.It is given that $|f'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in [0,2]$.Find $f(x)$ in $[0,2]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is differentiable in $[0,2]$.$f(0)=1,f(2)=3$.It is given that $|f'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in [0,2]$.Find $f(x)$ in $[0,2]$.

If I assume $f(x)$ to be linear, then, I get $f(x)=x+1$ which satisfies the conditions.
Are there more functions?

Comment: I think you should take $f(x)=2x+1$.

Comment: sorry edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no other function.

**Hint.** Consider $g(x) = f(x)-x-1$. If $g(c)> 0$ for some $c\in (0,2)$, then the mean value theorem would imply there is some $0<d<c$ such that $g'(d)> 0$.  What can we say about $f'(d)$? What happens if $g(c)<0$ for some $c$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof by contradiction:

For each $x \in (0,2)$ you have
$$f(x) - 1 = f(x) -f(0)=f'(\xi_x)(x-0) = f'(\xi_x)x \mbox{ with } \xi_x \in (0,x)\stackrel{|f'(x)|\leq 1}{\Rightarrow} |f(x) - 1| \leq x$$

Now, assume there is $c\in(0,2)$ with
$$f(c) -1 < c \Rightarrow f(c) < c+1$$
Then, there should be a $d \in (c,2)$ such that

$$\color{blue}{f'(d)} =\frac{f(2) - f(c)}{2-c} \color{blue}{>} \frac{f(2) - c -f(0)}{2-c} = \frac{3 - c - 1}{2-c} = \color{blue}{1}$$
This is a contradiction to $|f'(x)|\leq 1$ on $(0,2)$. It follows
$$f(x) = x+1$$